# How to find PixelFormat for decoded bitmap using SkiaSharp

Tags: asp.net-core, 2d, skia, skiasharp

In System.Drawing we retrieve the PixelFormat from Image object, but SkiaSharp.SkImage does not provide API to find the PixelFormat of decoded image. Whether it has any other workaround to find the PixelFormat of decoded images and also how can we create Image with PixelFormat value as equivalent of System.Drawing.Image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer

There is this aspect, but it is split into two types: `SKColorType` and `SKAlphaType`. These properties are found on the `SKImageInfo` type.

### `SKImage` vs `SKBitmap`

Before I share the real answer, a brief intro to the differences between the two image types.

#### `SKBitmap` *(raster only)*

A `SKBitmap` is a **raster-only graphic**, this means that the color and alpha type information is readily available. This is in the [`Info`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Info/) property.

```cs
SKBitmap bitmap = ...;
SKColorType colorType = bitmap.Info.ColorType;
SKAlphaType alphaType = bitmap.Info.AlphaType;
```

#### `SKImage` *(raster or texture)*

`SKImage` is a bit different in that it may not actually be a raster bitmap. An `SKImage` could be a GPU object, such as a OpenGL Texture. As such, this color type does not apply. So in your case where you are using raster bitmaps, use `SKBitmap` instead of `SKImage`.

However, there is still hope with `SKImage`, because a raster-based `SKImage` actually uses a `SKBitmap` under the hood. If you know your `SKImage` is a raster image, then you can use the `PeekPixels()` method to get a [`SKPixmap`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/SkiaSharp.SKPixmap/) object which will also have an `Info` property. `SKPixmap` is a thin type that contains a reference to the image data, the info and a few other properties.

*To check if a certain `SKImage` is a texture image or a raster image, you can use the `IsTextureBacked` property.*

```cs
SKImage image = ...;
if (!image.IsTextureBacked) {
    using (SKPixmap pixmap = image.PeekPixels()) {
        SKColorType colorType = pixmap.ColorType;
        SKAlphaType alphaType = pixmap.AlphaType;
    }
} else {
    // this is a texture on the GPU and can't be determined easily
}
```

### Longer answer

So now the longer answer... The `SKColorType` and `SKAlphaType` types together form the equivalent of the `PixelFormat`.

For example:

- `PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565` is equivalent to:
  [`SKColorType.Rgb565`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/SkiaSharp.SKColorType.Rgb565/) and [`SKAlphaType.Opaque`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/SkiaSharp.SKAlphaType.Opaque/)
- `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` is equivalent to:
  [`SKColorType.Rgba8888`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/SkiaSharp.SKColorType.Rgba8888/) (or [`SKColorType.Bgra8888`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/SkiaSharp.SKColorType.Bgra8888/) on Windows) and [`SKAlphaType.Unpremul`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/SkiaSharp.SKAlphaType.Unpremul/)
- `PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb` is equivalent to:
  [`SKColorType.Rgba8888`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/SkiaSharp.SKColorType.Rgba8888/) (or [`SKColorType.Bgra8888`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/SkiaSharp.SKColorType.Bgra8888/) on Windows) and [`SKAlphaType.Premul`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/SkiaSharp.SKAlphaType.Premul/)

The main difference between `Rgba8888` and `Bgra8888` is the platform that the app is running on. Typically, you would check the color type against the [`SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType/) as this will know what the native color type is supposed to be.